# How to change td.style when dynamic add table row

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript to add table rows dynamically, but I don't know how to change the style of the table data.
My code is:

```
var tableis = document.getElementById("cameraTable");
var last=(-1);
var Tr = tableis.insertRow(last);
var Td1 = Tr.insertCell(0);
Td1.innerHTML="<div name='mac"+i+"' id='mac"+i+"'>"+mac+"</div>";
Tr.appendChild(Td1);
```

and I only know how to change the background of the td:

```
Td1.bgColor="#00FF00";
```

I want to change the border style of the td, is it possible?
The style is like:

```
style="border: 1px solid black;"
```

I have tried `Td1.style="border: 1px solid black;"`
but it is no effort.

Any answer appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying a css class to your row ?

Comment: It appears that you're appending `div` elements not `td` elements...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the [**`HTMLElement.style`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style):

```
Td1.style.border = '1px solid black';
```

[**Simple Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PeSRL/)

Answer (score 5):

I think a more elegant solution would be to have the CSS class defined rather than hard-coding the style in the cell.

```
/* CSS Class */
.cellStyle{
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: #00FF00;
}

/* JavaScript Code */
Td1.className = 'cellStyle';
```